# How to check if mouse is over a notification window in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html

I need to close the notification window after X seconds only if user's mouse is not over the notification window being displayed.

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
  'icon.png',
  'Notification titile',
  'Notification body text'
);

notification.show();

// TODO: Close notification window only if user's mouse is not over it
setTimeout(function() { notification.cancel() }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched Chrome extensions for a while but the last time I did, you could use a HTML file as content for the notification.

So what I'd do is:

- If you can close the notification with JavaScript inside the notification, then just use the normal onmouseover/onmouseout to store in a boolean if the mouse is on the notification or not and launch the time out from within the notification as soon as it gets loaded.
- If you can't do the same thing but have the notification *talk* to the background page to make it close the notification.

Comment: Yeah, i know, but that complicates things, i would rather pass just text into createNotification() and figure out mouse location the other way around

Comment: Well. I don't think you can do that. Unless you can access the window object of the notification. which I don't think you can.

Comment: @GriefCoder It's impossible. You can try to open the Task Manager (Ctrl+Esc) and show a text notification. You'll find that the text notification has its own separate process so your extension has no access to it. It seems that you have to use HTML notifications.